# FileNotFoundError, хотя сам файл лежит в рабочей директории

Tags: python

Столкнулся с проблемой. Мне нужно воспользоваться веб драйвером для Firefox, я скачал его и положил в рабочую директорию с остальными файлами, с которыми я работаю. И при попытке вызова этого самого webdriver'а мне выдает ошибку FileNotFoundError.
Я пробовал воспользоваться этим:

```
os.getcwd()
#Вот, что мне выдало:
'/home/gleb/Documents/pyscripts/learninPython'
```

Так я удостоверился, что нахожусь в нужной рабочей директории.

Пробовал открыть файл разными способами, через `os.path.abspath`, через экранирование слэшей, еще добавляя "r" перед строкой. Ничего не помогает, поэтому спрашиваю, что можно с этим сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

Проблему решил добавлением в строку с вебдрайвером 'executable_path='

Итого, это выглядит вот так:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/home/gleb/Documents/pyscripts/learninPython/geckodriver')
```